# There is no button for changing display language in Windows Vista

Tags: windows, windows-vista, language

I have an really old Windows Vista Computer (Toshiba, Windows Vista Home Premium, 32-Bit (x86)) and I want to change the display language; I've followed the steps from the Microsoft website: Go to **Start**, **Control Panel**, select **Change keyboard or other input methods** under **Clock, Language and Region**, and then I have to select under **Display language** the language that I want (Sorry for my English). But the problem is: there is no *Display language* setting or something.

[image]

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the bottom link "How can I install an extra language"?

Comment: Yes, but then I get the same instructions I already tried out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Vista Home Premium doesn't support changing the display language /MUI](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-vista/install-a-display-language). Only Vista Ultimate / Enterprise  support it.

> The Display language section will be visible only if you have already
>   installed a language pack or if your edition of Windows supports
>   language packs. Language packs are available only in Windows Vista
>   Ultimate and Windows Vista Enterprise.

Microsoft changed this in Windows 8, now all editions can change it.